# Informatica Metadata Exchange (MX) Views show the object deleted

Tags: metadata, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I used the PowerCenter Metadata Exchange to query.

There is a view REP_ALL_SOURCES who can provides a list of the latest version of sources defined in each folder of a repository.

But when i used this view, i find that it shows the sources deleted too. I did't find the field who can filter the object deleted. so for REP_ALL_MAPPINGS, REP_LOAD_SESSIONS are the same.

who can please tell me how to show the object only exist?

Best wishes,
Zhixin

Comment: (1) I cannot confirm this behaviour - I have just deleted a source, **checked it in** and it is no longer present in `REP_ALL_SOURCES`. (2) Can you elaborate on `so for REP_ALL_MAPPINGS, REP_LOAD_SESSIONS are the same`? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Marek Grzenkowicz, thank for your reponse. I checked out the source, and i chosed 'Delete from the Folder'. and this source is no longer visible? how can i check in?           REP_ALL_MAPPINGS, REP_LOAD_SESSIONS are the same means  the view of   REP_ALL_MAPPINGS and REP_LOAD_SESSIONS  show the object deleted too.

Comment: In repository manager, choose the particular folder. Then go to _Versioning -> Find Checkouts_. This will give you the list of objects that are checked out including the deleted objects. Select the objects that you deleted and then check-in.